# How to open the properties dialog for a Complex Property without a PropertyGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, uitypeeditor

Consider a form with some custom `UserControl` and a `Button`.

In Visual Studio designer, you can click the button off to the right of your property (like you would when you change other common properties on controls such as `Font` or `Image`) and use the Editor for this property.

During runtime, if you've added a `PropertyGrid` to the form and point it to this `UserControl`, you can also click the button off to the right of that complex property at runtime and get the same `UITypeEditor` dialog.

How can I get this editor window to come up during run-time through say, a button click without having a `PropertyGrid` on the form?

Though I've gotten the `PropertyDescriptor` and the `UITypeEditor` from this descriptor, I don't know what to call to get the instances of `ITypeDescriptorContext` and `IServiceProvider` when calling `UITypeEditor.EditValue` to get the editor to display.

This is related to building a custom UITypeEditor for a property: [Building Windows Forms Controls and Components with Rich Design-Time Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164145.aspx).  In this case, I've already configured all of this and it all works beautifully so I just want to call the editor window at runtime.

Comment: Here's a duplicate question, with pretty much no useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047277/using-ui-editor-at-runtime-on-a-button-click.  :/

Answer (score 0):

I you had managed to implement a `TypeDescriptor`, you almost done.
This may be a start for you:

```
public class MyEditor: UITypeEditor {

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService  service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        if (service != null) {
            SomeControl ctrl = new SomeControl();
            ctrl.XYZ = ...
            service.DropDownControl(ctrl);
            value = ctrl.XYZ;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

WinForms handles the rest of it.

Return `UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal` form `GetEditStyle` and also use `service.ShowDialog(ctrl)`, if you have a form instead of a  control.